# vimeo php api add video tags

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

this is my code

```
$my_data = array(
     "name" => "Sequence 01",
     "description" => "Video uploading test sequence 01",
     "tags" => array( "hello", "hi" )
);
$update = $vimeo_obj->request( $uri, $my_data, 'PATCH' );
```

it updates name and description of video. however it does not add tags to video.
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support to update video tags via `PATCH /videos/{video_id}` currently.

To add tags to your video make a request via `PUT /videos/{video_id}/tags` with a payload of

```
"data" => [
 ["name" => "tag_text_1"],
 ["name" => "tag_text_2"]
]
```

Comment: $my_data = array ( 
    array( "name" => "hello" ),
    array( "name" => "hi" )     
);
$update = $vimeo_obj->request( $uri, $my_data, 'PUT' );
It works great, thanks @SageVentour